# getting row value from datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarow

```
Dim flag As Boolean = True

Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)

Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)

Dim fileLocation As String = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" & fileName)

'Check whether file extension is xls or xslx
If fileExtension = ".xls" Then
    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & fileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
ElseIf fileExtension = ".xlsx" Then
    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
End If

'Create OleDB Connection and OleDb Command

Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand()
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = con
Dim dAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dtExcelRecords As New DataTable()
con.Open()
Dim dtExcelSheetName As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
Dim getExcelSheetName As String = dtExcelSheetName.Rows(0)("Table_Name").ToString()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & getExcelSheetName & "]"
dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords)
con.Close()

Dim row As DataRow
For Each row In dtExcelRecords.Rows
    If Include.ConvertDbNullToEmpyString(row(2)) = "" Then
        MsgBox("Error in saving!")
        Exit For

    End If
    MsgBox(row(0) & " " & row(1) & " " & row(2) & " " & row(3))
Next


GridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords

GridView1.DataBind()
ViewState("file") = dtExcelRecords


Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet("dataSet")
dataSet.Tables.Add(dtExcelRecords)
'' Display the DataSet contents as XML.
Console.WriteLine(dataSet.Tables(0).DataSet.GetXml())
```

I had code which use to upload file excel into datatable and show at gridview.

After show at gridview, the excel value which has been convert into datatable and showed at gridview will be saved to database.

My problem :

```
Dim row As DataRow
For Each row In dtExcelRecords.Rows
    If Include.ConvertDbNullToEmpyString(row(2)) = "" Then
        MsgBox("Error in saving!")
        Exit For
    End If
    MsgBox(row(0) & " " & row(1) & " " & row(2) & " " & row(3))
Next
```

that was code to get the row value.

But how to set datatable with new data row?

If I had null value in row 2, I wanted proses input data to datatable will stoped!
And showing with new value from datarow value into gridView.

-------------------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------

example :

upload file excel :

> col1 ---- col2 ---- col3 ---- col4

> tes1 ---- test1 ---- test1 ---- test1

> tes2 ---- test2 ----       ---- test2

> tes3 ---- test3 ---- test3 ---- test3

> tes4 ---- test4 ----       ---- test4

and the result at gridview must like this :

> col1 ---- col2 ---- col3 ---- col4

> tes1 ---- test1 ---- test1 ---- test1

> tes3 ---- test3 ---- test3 ---- test3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
                Dim dtData As DataTable
                dtData = New DataTable
                dtData.Columns.Add("Row0")
                dtData.Columns.Add("Row1")
                dtData.Columns.Add("Row2")
                dtData.Columns.Add("Row3")

                Dim row As DataRow
                For Each row In dtExcelRecords.Rows
                    If Include.ConvertDbNullToEmpyString(row(2)) = "" Then
                        MsgBox("Error in saving!")
                        Exit For 'or exit Sub
                    End If
                    Dim dr As DataRow = dtData.NewRow

                    dr("Row0") = row(0)
                    dr("Row1") = row(1)
                    dr("Row2") = row(2)
                    dr("Row3") = row(3)

                    dtData.Rows.Add(dr) 'Add this line

                Next

                'Bind dtData to gridview
                'Save data in dtData to database
```

Comment: Nice... @nalaka thanks a lot, your code is working for adding per row but the gridview not showing the value. I think after exit the loop, all value goes missing so all value not showing at gridview

Comment: @tyo I'm so sorry, It was missing one line, Now fixed it... (edited answer, add this line 'dtData.Rows.Add(dr)')

Answer (score 0):

if you change the Exit For to Exit Sub then you will stop processing at that point

Comment: my problem is how to set the value in row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3) which had proses in for each into datatable!